# Pointer assignment causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have the following code that gives the error: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (code=2, address=0x100000000). The error is due to this line of code: `sub->str = s;`.
I don't quite comprehend why this is the case since I am passing the address of a `char` (i.e. `s`) to a pointer of a `char` (i.e. `sub->str`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Index {
    char *str;
};

typedef struct Index ind;

int fxn_one(char *s)
{
    ind *sub;
    sub->str = s;   // Error due to this line of code.
    return (0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *p = "test";
    int ret = fxn_one(p);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What is `sub` pointing to? It is uninitialised, so it may point anywhere. You can't just write to random memory.

Comment: `ind *sub;` declares an uninitialized pointer. You need to point it at something. One way would be `ind *sub = malloc(sizeof(*sub));`, but you also need to keep track of that pointer so you can free it later. Right now it is lost as soon as the function ends resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I had miss understood that aspect of pointers, mistook it for null pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
ind *sub;
```

You are instructing the compiler to use 4/8 bytes, depending to your system architecture, to contain a pointer to the struct `ind` (an address). This pointer is stored in the *stack area*, as it is a local variable of the function `fxn_one`.

What is this address? It depends to the value assigned to it. **But you never assign anything to it** so it will contain anything present at that moment in the stack: usually garbage; for sure **not a valid address**.

Writing in it, or accessing a field of the struct pointed to it (that will be invalid as well) will cause undefined behavior, so raising `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is a gentle way to alert you about... the bad access.

---

What you need to do is to allocate the structure in order to have a valid address.

1. You can `malloc` it. But pay attention: you will need to change the function prototype otherwise you won't be able to access it later, especially to `free` it:

   ```
   ind * fxn_one(char *s)
   {
       ind *sub = malloc(sizeof (ind));

       //Recommended: check if malloc returned NULL, in case it wasn't able to allocate the heap you requested
       sub->str = s;   //In this case the address will be valid
       return ind;
   }

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       char *p = "test";
       ind * data = fxn_one(p);

       free (data);

       return (0);
   }
   ```
2. Point to an alredy existing struct, for example to a global variable:

   ```
   //Global struct
   ind gl_ind = { NULL };

   int fxn_one(char *s)
   {
       ind *sub = &gl_ind;

       sub->str = s;   //Also in this case the address will be valid
       return (0);
   }
   ```

   In this case you don't need to change the interface of `fxn_one`.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I went ahead with suggestion 2.